# Read file in java until one row is found

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a file that looks like this:

```
color1 red
color2 blue
color3 white
end
color1 blue
color2 green
end
color1 black
color2 white
color3 red
end
```

I want to read this file and put the data between `end` in an `ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>>`

My code:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>> getColors (String path) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>> allColors = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>>();

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            String line = null;
            ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> color = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
                String color = tokens[0];
                String colorValue = tokens[1];
                HashMap<String,String> colorWithValue = new HashMap<String,String>();
                colorWithValue.put(color, colorValue);

                color.add(colorWithValue);
            }
            allColors.add(color);
            br.close();         
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return allColors;
    }
```

The question is how I can stop when I find an `end` and start over, constructing a new `ArrayList` of colors?

Comment: look for a line that gives only one token when you split it, and that token is end: `tokens[0].equals("end")`

Comment: Why are you creating a list of lists of single-item hash maps? This doesn't seem to be a structure you'll be able to easily get colors from.

Comment: Have you heard about try-with-resources? It's useful in this case.

Comment: ey @fabian, i like your idea... could you "upgrate" my code in order to show how to do it employing modern features of Java? (Although it would be nice to keep my example for those how are just starting to learn).

Comment: @Victor: Of course... IF you make it community wiki... But you could easily do it yourself. Just move the declaration/initialisation of `br` to `()` brackets after the `try` and remove `br.close();`. Here's a tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this.

```
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if ("end".equals(line.trim())) {
                 allColors.add(color);
                 color = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
            }
            else {
            String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
            String color = tokens[0];
            String colorValue = tokens[1];
            HashMap<String,String> colorWithValue = new HashMap<String,String>();
            colorWithValue.put(color, colorValue);

            color.add(colorWithValue);
            }
        }
        br.close();
```

P.S: Your `allColors` is so deep that I am seeing rainbows in them...

Answer (score 1):

If you insists in using that approach, I would suggest to use this algorithm.

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> getColors(String path)
{
    ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> allColors = new ArrayList<>();

    try
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        String line;
        do 
        {
            line = br.readLine();
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> colors = new ArrayList<>();
            while (line != null && !"end".equals(line)) { 
                String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
                String color = tokens[0];
                String colorValue = tokens[1];
                HashMap<String, String> colorWithValue = new HashMap<>();
                colorWithValue.put(color, colorValue);

                colors.add(colorWithValue);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            allColors.add(colors);
        } while (line != null);
        br.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return allColors;
}
```

But you can achieve it using other algorithms. You could lower the complexity of the algorithm by using other structures. You know, never in my life has to use such deep nested structure like: `ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`.

Think on using other abstractions or classes to lower the complexity if you are learning; that would be my final advice.

Also note your code has a variable duplicated: "color".